# Passing json array of object to a component via useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to react typescript.  I am searching for hours and no solution.
I have a json object saved inside of file categories.ts like

```
const categories = [
  {value: "Farsi", label: "fa"},
  {value: "English", label: "en"},
  {value: "Hindi", label: "hi"},
  {value: "Spanish", label: "es"},
  {value: "French", label: "fr"},
  {value: "Japanese", label: "ja"},
  {value: "Russian", label: "ru"},
  {value: "German", label: "de"},
  {value: "Italian", label: "it"},
  {value: "Korean", label: "ko"},
  {value: "Brazilian Portuguese", label: "pt-BR"},
  {value: "Arabic", label: "ar"},
  {value: "Turkish", label: "tr"}
];

export default categories;
```

This is the code I am working which is saved inside a utility file called useDictionary.ts

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import categories from "../data/categories";
    
    type dataCategoryType = {
      value: string;
      label: string;
    }
    
    const useDictionary = () => {
        
        const [category, setCategory] = useState<dataCategoryType[]>([]);

        // setCategory(<dataCategoryType[]> JSON.parse(categories));
     const cat: DataCategoryType = <dataCategoryType[]> JSON.parse(categories);
    setCategory(cat);

   return {
        category
    };
    
    export default useDictionary;
```

the error is

```
Argument of type '{ value: string; label: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)
(alias) const categories: {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}[]
import categories
```

can you please tell me the proper way of seasoned typescript folks do this?
Please also note the returned value category is passed to APP component. like

```
const { category } = useDictionary();
```

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: The first thing wrong with your code is that you are treating categories as a JSON whereas it is an Object (javascript ARRAY), so, JSON.parse would keep throwing an error, get rid of the parse

Secondly, if you are going to set the category state, you can do that directly on the useState initialization `const [category, setCategory] = useState<dataCategoryType[]>(categories);` and get rid of the cat variable and the setCategory beneath that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:**

- JSON.parse is used to convert json from string. But your data exported from categories.ts file is already an array. so no need to parse it.
- As the *categories* is a const, we can easily initialize the hook state with this value. no need to initialize the state with empty array first and then call setState to store data.

**Updated Code:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import categories from "../data/categories";

type dataCategoryType = {
value: string;
label: string;
}

type UseDictionaryType = {
categories: dataCategoryType[];
}

const useDictionary = (): UseDictionaryType => {
    
const [category, setCategory] = useState<dataCategoryType[]>(categories);

return { category };

}
    
export default useDictionary;
```

You can also provide a return type for useDictionary hook. Normally we also return the **setCategory** here from the hook so that we can update the categories from outside of this hook. But it depends on your use case also.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you much.  So passing to App component was successful.   Now I am trying to pass it to Search component from Appt.  In search component category is expected to be imported as dataCategoryType, but no matter what I do it comes in as type Any.  Is there a way to send you snippet of what I have?

Comment: you can paste your snippet here.

Comment: Never mind, everything is working like charm.  Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make my comment to be an answer.

The first thing wrong with your code is that you are treating categories as a JSON whereas it is an Object (javascript ARRAY), so, JSON.parse would keep throwing an error, and get rid of the parse, meaning the code needs to look like this.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import categories from "../data/categories";

type dataCategoryType = {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}

const useDictionary = () => {
    const [category, setCategory] = useState<dataCategoryType[]>([]);
    const cat: dataCategoryType = categories;
    setCategory(cat);

    return {
        category
    };
}

export default useDictionary;
```

Now we've fixed that, if you are going to set the category state (that you already have before hand), you can do that directly on the `useState` initialization.

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState<dataCategoryType[]>(categories);
```

and get rid of the cat variable and the setCategory beneath that, final code should look like this.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import categories from "../data/categories";

type dataCategoryType = {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}

const useDictionary = () => {
    const [category, setCategory] = useState<dataCategoryType[]>(categories); // set the initial value to be our categories array

    return {
        category
    };
}

export default useDictionary;
```